# SQL replace value in a field in a row if it exists, else create a row and populate that value

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

My request is a little strange and specific, please bear with me.

I have an Access 2003 database with a `Comments` table that has several hundred thousand lines in it. There are several fields - let's call them `A, B, C, D` and `comment`. Columns `A-C` form the PK of the table. Thus, you could have 5, 10, or 50 rows which have different comments, but all pertain to the `A-C` PK.

I have another table called `CORE` which contains a table `core` that has fields `A, B, C, D` (`A-C` PK) and `comment_value_insert`.

What I want to do:

In `Comments`, for each "set" of identical `A-C` rows (Field `D` can differ), if none of their `comment` values matches a certain value (let's call it `critical`), then look up the same row in `CORE` and insert into the `comments` table a new row with `A-D` and `Comments.comment = core.comment_value_insert`.

I'm not even sure if this is possible with SQL (perhaps VBA? Hence the tag). Any advice anyone?
For further clarification please ask away.

Huge thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

To demonstrate exactly what I want:

If my `Comments` table looks like

```
A | B | C | D | Comment
1   2   3   b   val1
1   2   3   x   val2
1   2   3   a   val3
2   9   8   z   val4
2   9   8   a   val5
3   3   3   x   val6
END
```

And my `CORE` Table looks like

```
A | B | C | D | Comment_value_insert
1   2   3   u   critical1
2   9   8   t   critical2
4   8   6   x   critical3
END
```

Then I'd want the `critical1` row from `CORE` to be inserted into `Comments`, as well as the `critical2` row, but not the `critical3` row.

Then the final product in the `Comments` table will be

```
A | B | C | D | Comment
1   2   3   b   val1
1   2   3   x   val2
1   2   3   a   val3
1   2   3   u   critical1
2   9   8   z   val4
2   9   8   a   val5
2   9   8   t   critical2
3   3   3   x   val6
END
```

Comment: So you want to do this in SQL or Access?

Comment: If you can have more than one comment for each A-D "set", then A-D is not the PK of the Comments table. Let's say A-D+comment or A-D,commentID is, right? Also, the heading of your question talks about replacing values, and create the row only if it doesn't exist, but you dont say anything of it in your question's body.

Comment: Another question: Where in the "Comments" table should the query look for the value "Critical", in the "comment" field? Is this a static value? Or should it look for the value contained in the core.comment_value_insert field? If you look for a static value like "Critical", and the corresponding value in the "Core" table is, let's say, "Hello", the query would try to insert a new record A,B,C,D,"Hello" whenever you invoked it, since this doesn't change the circumstance that there isn't a A,B,C,D,"Critical" record on the "Comments" table. Right?

Comment: @twoleggedhorse the two would be the same in this case? I'm using Access 2003 and am thinking there's an SQL solution for this

Comment: @Clon ah yes, my bad - let's say that D is, like the comment field also not a PK.

In the "Comments" table, the query should be looking to see if the value "critical" exists in the "comment" field - this field is static. If the "comments" field does NOT contain the "critical" value for the entire set of A-C rows, then copy in the row from CORE with the comment_value_insert value (which would be "critical").

Hope that made a bit more sense.

Comment: @Clon question updated for clarity

Comment: Thanks, that's more clear now. Still, A,B,C is not the PK in the Comments table. That would make a good foreign key to reference an entity in another table. But a PK places a unique restriction, so it would be impossible to have more than one record with '1,2,3' or '2,9,8' PK. I think that the PK for Comments is (maybe) A,B,C,D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this for the INSERT part. For the UPDATE part you should provide more information.

-- EDIT --

```
INSERT INTO Comments ( A, B, C, D, Comment )
SELECT DISTINCT C.A, C.B, C.C, C.D, C.comment_value_insert
FROM Core AS C INNER JOIN Comments as C1 ON C.A = C1.A and C.B = C1.B and C.C = C1.C
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Comments AS O WHERE O.Comment = "Critical" AND O.A = C.A AND O.B = C.B AND O.C = C.C);
```

Regards,

Comment: this seems to address a large part of my issue (let's forget about the update for now - I can just let the query leave those rows). The issue now is that the query seems to be returning values from CORE  that don't actually exist in the Comments table. Currently my Comments table has 3212 rows, while the CORE table has 27132. Your query will return 26314.

Comment: Well, that is important. I made the query so that it would insert the records that didn't exist in the Comments table. I've added a JOIN clause to ensure that the key (A,B,C) previously exists in the comments table. I think it should work now.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you - I have been travelling. This works; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

** This version worked for me **

```
INSERT INTO comments  
SELECT a, 
       b, 
       c, 
       d, 
       comment_value_insert AS comment  
FROM   core  
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT comments.*  
               FROM   comments  
               WHERE  core.c = comments.c  
                      AND core.b = comments.b  
                      AND core.a = comments.a)  
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT comments.*  
                       FROM   comments  
                       WHERE  core.c = comments.c  
                              AND core.b = comments.b  
                              AND core.a = comments.a  
                              AND core.comment_value_insert = comments.comment)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this ends up achieving what I want - it throws quite a few errors no matter how I modify it...

Please see my edited question for an example in action